# including limit to select top n rows within a group by clause

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following 2 tables:

```
create table1
(
   SENDER int,
   RECEIVER int,
   TIME time,
   TYPE char(1)
);

create table2
(
   ID int,
   Y int,
   CONTACT int,
   DATE time
);
```

I am executing the following join query:

```
SELECT B.ID, A.RECEIVER AS Z, A.SENDER AS CONTACT, A.TYPE, A.TIME
FROM table1 A 
JOIN table2 B ON A.RECEIVER = B.CONTACT 
WHERE A.TYPE = 'A'
   AND A.TIME < B.DATE
```

How do I modify the query to return only the top 40 results for each `(ID,CONTACT)` pair using `GROUP BY`?

I can order the data using the field `table2.DATE`

Comment: GROUP BY implies consolidation, 'top' implies ranking but you've provided no details of how the data should be aggregated nor how it should be ranked.

Comment: If u are trying to retrieve only 40 records u can use `LIMIT`

Comment: @Shirish11 if i use limit, then the total no of records retreived would be 40, whereas i want the max no of records for each group to be 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i wanted top 40 results for each ID, i made ID,autoId as a primary key, here autoId is an autoincrement key. so after executing the following query:
`SELECT B.ID, A.RECEIVER AS Z, A.SENDER AS CONTACT, A.TYPE, A.TIME
FROM table1 A 
JOIN table2 B ON A.RECEIVER = B.CONTACT 
WHERE A.TYPE = 'A'
   AND A.TIME < B.DATE`
i get results such that, the autoId initializes to 1 for each ID
for eg:

ID CONTACT autoId 
1        2           1 
1        3           2 
1        11        3 
1        34        4 
2        5           1 
2        33        2 
2        56        3

since autoId is autoincrement, there is already an index on it. after this table is created, i can easily delete the results where autoId is greater than 40. and this while process runs really fast!